# Export HTML Table Data to Excel using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel, axios

I tried to follow the reference : [export HTML to Excel using JavaScript](https://www.codexworld.com/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript/). It works for the first three columns of my data. But the last two columns, which I used nested axios to find out more data), are not working. I am not sure if the **nested axios** could be the issue.

- In my local test, I can see the whole data (or when I `console.log("tableSelect")`, I still can see the whole data
- After I export to excel, I can only see the first three columns data, the rest two are blanks

```
import Axios from "axios";

window.onload = function (){
const exportExcelBtn = document.getElementById("Export-Excel");

const body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
const tbl = document.createElement("table");
tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
tbl.setAttribute("id", "tblId");
const tblbody = document.createElement("tbody");

const getFieldsFromApi = async () => {
    const GetUrl = "abc.net"
    const Doorkey = {username: "token", password: "token"}

    const response = await Axios.get(GetUrl, {auth: Doorkey})
    return response.data.users
}

const getData = async () => {
    const values = await getFieldsFromApi()
    values.forEach(field => {
        const row = document.createElement("tr");
        row.appendChild(addCell(field.name));
        row.appendChild(addCell(field.email));
        row.appendChild(addCell(field.role_type));            
        row.appendChild(addCellBrand(field.id));              // when export to excel, this data is not shown 
        row.appendChild(addCellLanguage(field.locale_id));    // when export to excel, this data is not shown         
        tblbody.appendChild(row);
    })
    tbl.appendChild(tblbody);
    body.appendChild(tbl);
    const exportTableToExcel = (tbl, filename = "") => {
        let downloadLink;
        const dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
        const tableSelect = document.getElementById(tbl);
        let tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
        // Specify file name
        filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';          
        // Create download link element
        downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

        if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
            let blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
                type: dataType
            });
            navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename );
        }else{
            // Create a link to the file
            downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;

            // Setting the file name
            downloadLink.download = filename;
                    
            //triggering the function
            downloadLink.click();
        }
                
        };
        exportTableToExcel(tbl.id); //this is export the excel file
};

const addCell = value => {
    const cell = document.createElement("td");
    const cellText = document.createTextNode(value);
    cell.appendChild(cellText);

    return cell
}

const addCellBrand = value => {
    const cell = document.createElement("td");
    const getBrandFromApi = async () => {
        const GetUrl = `abc.net/${value}`
        const Doorkey = {username: "token", password: "token"}
    
        const response = await Axios.get(GetUrl, {auth: Doorkey})
        const getData = response.data.organizations[0].name
        const cellText = document.createTextNode(getData); 
        cell.appendChild(cellText);
    }
    getBrandFromApi();

    return cell
}

const addCellLanguage = value => {
    const cell = document.createElement("td");
    const getLanguageFromApi = async () => {
        const GetUrl = `abc.net/${value}/fieldList`
        const Doorkey = {username: "token", password: "token"}
    
        const response = await Axios.get(GetUrl, {auth: Doorkey})
        const getData = response.data.locale.presentation_name
        const cellText = document.createTextNode(getData); 
        cell.appendChild(cellText);     
    }
    getLanguageFromApi();

    return cell
}

exportExcelBtn.addEventListener("click", getData);
}
```

Please can someone help to see what could be the issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `addCellBrand` and `addCellLanguage` functions. They are **asynchronous** and you need to wait at the end to `return cell`, but in the `addCell` function, you are trying to do **synchronous** action and returning the `cell` at the end of the function's block properly.

So, you need to do your async action correctly:

in the `addCellBrand` and `addCellLanguage` function (they are similar so do the same for addCellLanguage):

```
const addCellBrand = (value) => {
    const cell = document.createElement("td");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const getBrandFromApi = async () => {
        const GetUrl = `abc.net/${value}`;
        const Doorkey = { username: "token", password: "token" };

        try {
          const response = await Axios.get(GetUrl, {auth: Doorkey});
          const getData = response.data.organizations[0].name
          const cellText = document.createTextNode(getData);
          cell.appendChild(cellText);
          resolve(cell); // here for returning your cell after all
        } catch (err) {
          reject(cell);  // don't forgot about the failure case on your API call
        }
      };
      getBrandFromApi();
    });
  };
```

Now, you are implemented an **asynchronous** function to get the `cell` properly with creating a new promise.

It's time to use this async method in the `getData`:

```
const values = await getFieldsFromApi()
values.forEach(async (field) => {
    const cellBrand = await addCellBrand(field.id) 
    const cellLanguage = await addCellLangugae(field.local_id)

    const row = document.createElement("tr");
    row.appendChild(addCell(field.name));
    row.appendChild(addCell(field.email));
    row.appendChild(addCell(field.role_type));            
    row.appendChild(cellBrand);
    row.appendChild(cellLanguage);         
    tblbody.appendChild(row);
})
```

Comment: Thanks @nima. However, after I revised the code, the `tbl.appendChild(tblbody)` doesn't have data anymore. Do you think I need to add another Promise for `values.forEach(async (field) => { ... }` ? Because I still can see the data in `tblbody.appendChild(row)`

Comment: I suggest you create a codesandbox for further checking, the problem might be with `async/await` on `forEach` as you mentioned, but without the playground, it's hard to debug the program @MoonFactory

Comment: That's right. After do more survey, [async await doesn't work in the forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788046/async-await-with-foreach-and-axios/52789175). But now the problem is solved. Thanks a lot!